# How to create a dynamic const name for an array using dropdown options in reactjs or nextjs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dynamic, next.js

Is it possible to create a dynamic const name of an array using dropdown options?

```
Import {array1, array2, array3} from './myfilesystem/arrays';

const somename = array1;
```

Comment: You're going to need to work on this question. Not only is the syntax completely invalid, but the question itself just doesn't make sense. Are you trying to change a variable name at runtime based on the selected value in a <select> element? What is your end goal?

Comment: I simplified question, my end goal is to use 1 page for this task instead of many, basically I have 1 function which acts as a key and tells the app which array to pull data from to send to other functions inside the app. So the variable name just needs to change. So I can use 1 page, while not loading ALL of the arrays, just the 1 needed. Due to the length of the arrays I read a post that stated when using react, to not combine into ONE array file like, {allArrays} but to keep broken into seperate exports {array1, array2, array3}, which leads to that const name issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. Put your arrays in a keyed object.
2. Put the keys in the drop-down.
3. Put the selected key in a variable.
4. Use the *value* of that variable to look up the array in the object.

Like this:

```
const arrays = {
  array1: [...],
  array2: [...],
  array3: [...]
}

const optionsForDropdown = Object.keys(arrays) // ["array1", "array2",...]

function returnSelectedArray(selectedKey) {
  return arrays[selectedKey]
}
```

So if you call `returnSelectedArray("array1")` or you do:

```
const key = "array1"
returnSelectedArray(key)
```

you will get `arrays.array1` back.

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as arr from '..pathname'

//  ..and somewhere in your code..
const someArray = arr.array1
```

is that what u ment?

*imports/exports* :

exporting from a file, has many syntax variants

```
// explicit exports
export const PI = 3.14159
export const cylinderVolume = (r, h) => {....}

//export as an object..
const PI = 3.14159
const cylinderVolume = (r, h) => {....}

export { PI, cylinderVolume }

// default export
export default PI = 3.14159
export const cylinderVolume = (r, h) => {....}

imports

// importing explict exports
import { PI, cylinderVolume } from 'path'

//importing default and explict exports(PI is default and cylinderVolume is explict)
import PI, { cylinderVolume } from 'path'

// importing as whole..

import * as shape from 'path'
// useage..
const cylinderSurfaceArea = (r, h) => 2*shape.PI*r ( r + h )
```

Re-export from another file..

```
export { cylinderVolume } from 'path'
// re-exporting as default..
export { default as PI } from 'path'
```

comparing some impacts on size on usecases:

```
import _ from 'lodash' // use case..
import * as shape from 'path' // same effect..
```

this will import the entire module and has a huge effect on the project size. however if we are using libs like lodash this is the way they recommend.

```
import { get, has } from 'lodash'
import { PI, cylinderVolume } from 'path'
```

surprisingly this don't have any much size diffrence comparing with the above syntax.

**Tree Shaking**

Modern build tools (webpack and others) bundle modules together and optimize them to speedup loading and remove unused stuff.

so, in order to minimize the impact on size the recommended syntax would be

```
import get from 'lodash/get'
```

but still when we have to import a whole load of stuff it's not practical(or recommended/ideal for the sake of readability)..

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.